# create service from shell script on ubuntu 14

Tags: bash, shell, service, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to create a service script in /etc/init.d to run my shell script wich is under /home/user !!

here a part of my script :

```
#! /bin/sh


 # PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
 PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/user/workspace/eattogether/app-server/app.server.core/target/wisdom
 DESC="chameleon service"
 NAME=chameleon.sh
 DAEMON=/home/user/workspace/eattogether/app-server/app.server.core/target/wisdom/$NAME
 DAEMON_ARGS="start"
 PIDFILE=/home/user/workspace/eattogether/app-server/app.server.core/target/wisdom/CHAMELEON.pid
 SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/spheros

 # Exit if the package is not installed
 [ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

 # Read configuration variable file if it is present
 [ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

 # Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
do_start()
 {
     start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
         || return 1
     start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
         $DAEMON_ARGS \
         || return 2

 }

 do_stop()
 {
     start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
     RETVAL="$?"
     start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
     [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
     rm -f $PIDFILE
     return "$RETVAL"
 }   

 case "$1" in
   start)
     log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
     do_start
     case "$?" in
         0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
         2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
     esac
     ;;
```

when I tr to execute this script i got an error : cannot access ./bin/*.jar: No such file or directory

here my other script :

```
# Check if the RUNNING_PID file is not there already
if [ -f RUNNING_PID ]; then
    echo "[error] RUNNING_PID existing. Is this chameleon already running?"
    exit 1
fi

#CLASSPATH=$(JARS=("bin"/*.jar); IFS=:; echo "${JARS[*]}")
for i in `ls ./bin/*.jar`
do
  CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${i}
done

if test "$1" = "--interactive"; then
    "$JAVA" -cp ${CLASSPATH} ${JVM_ARGS} -Dchameleon.home=$dir org.ow2.chameleon.core.Main "$@"
else
    "$JAVA" -cp ${CLASSPATH} ${JVM_ARGS} -Dchameleon.home=$dir org.ow2.chameleon.core.Main "$@" &
    echo $! > RUNNING_PID
fi
```

any idea how to resolve this ?? tell the service to use the directory where the script is located ???

Comment: Try "sh -x <yourscript.sh>" and see where it's trying/failing to find the data/file. Does $PATH has /home/user in it. Try "export PATH=/home/user:$PATH" and see if that helps. Other way you can debug is to use "echo xxxx" statements just before a statement in .sh file to see whether your script reaches a given statement. Do a "echo `pwd`" just before your "for" loop in your second script to see where you are when that portion of your script is running and what you'd do to get that ./bin/*.jar things. Create a variable "bin_dir=/path/to/parent/of/bin/dir" and use `ls $bin_dir/bin/*.jar`

Answer (score 1):

thanks jackman for the reply,

I did found a solution for this issue. I decided to use :

start-stop-daemon --chdir /path/to/my/script

this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to the daemon script:

```
cd -P "$(dirname "$0")"
```

But don't do this:

```
for i in `ls ./bin/*.jar`
```

do this instead

```
for i in ./bin/*.jar
```

and let the shell expand the filenames for you.

You should quote variables like `"$this"` not like `${this}`

Comment: I can't edit the second script file (generated one ) this is why i can't use your solution, but any way thank you for your help !! it will help me in the futur :-)